# How do you send an e-mail from Windows Phone 7?

Tags: email, windows-phone-7

What's the function for sending e-mails from WP7?  I'm trying to set up a button to send feedback e-mail, but I can't find the right function.

Thanks,

Zain

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it.  You need to use the EmailComposeTask class.  Here's a sample:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

...

void SendEmail(){
  EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
  email.To = "receiver@stuff.com";
  email.Subject = "hey";
  email.Body = "Wazaaaaaaaaaaap! How you doin?";
  email.Show();   
}
```

Comment: Just a heads-up, you'll want to put the Show() in a try/catch because it will crash if the user spams the button multiple times very quickly.